# ArcGIS Report designer Attachment placement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, attachments, reports

I would like to know if it is possible for me to manually place each attachment where I would like within report designer?

The issue that I'm having when using the _ATTACHREL within the related report window is that when the report is run the attachments are showing up one after another.

I would like to be able to place them horizontal instead of vertical.

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of what you are experiencing before and after you run the report?

Comment: Here ya go: [Before](http://i.imgur.com/jGZEBJx.png).        [After](http://i.imgur.com/9CLu12J.png)

Comment: So for some features you have multiple images and you would like them to run across horizontally of one another versus vertically as the image you provided displays?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Have you attempted to add the image frames horizontally across the report than run the report with the appropriate fields connected? I believe that is the answer, I want to post. If I had the dataset I could run some tests and tell you for sure.

Comment: Yea I cant give you the actual data set because I'm under an NDA with the utility company. I have tried to put the frames horrizontally how ever it just does 3 rows of all the attachments. How do I attach the appropriate fields? I have not seen an option as to how to assign that.

Comment: How about adding multiple picture frame horizontally, and specify each one to the the field _ATTACHREL?

Answer (score 1):

Esri provides documentation [Adding images to reports](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/reports/adding-images-to-reports.htm) which provides a good overview and the steps needed to accomplish this in the Report Designer.

You must keep in mind that the setting of the image frame and location of image is key.

> While you are designing the layout of your report, use a Picture control if you want to add an image to your report. Picture controls include an Image Source property that allows you to choose the source of your image from three options. The three image source options are 1) Choose a field, 2) Use a file path to a local, network, or web location, and 3) Use a static image.

I went about aligning the images horizontally and would set the image source for the report layout, as indicated below.

[image]